# Unfade downvoted posts

Tags: script

Answer to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/129593/178438).

Allows one to unfade downvoted posts.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/antifadepost.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/antifadepost.user.js)

### Usage

Mouse over a faded post to unfade it. Mousing out will bring it back to the unfaded state. If you don't like if flashing in and out of existence, click the post to keep it unfaded.